# Make [FromQuery] bool testValue accept 'testValue', 'test_value' and 'test-value'

Tags: asp.net-core

In **ASP NET 6+** I need to make `[FromQuery]` replace underscores `_` and minuses `-` before matching names.

So I want to plumb ASP to allow `[FromQuery] bool testValue` to be equivalent to all at once:

- `[FromQuery(Name="testValue")] bool testValue`
- `[FromQuery(Name="test-value")] bool testValue`
- `[FromQuery(Name="test_value")] bool testValue`

Is there a place in the pipeline I can get in before names are compared *(to remove `_` and `-` myself)*?

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is just to replace the `Request.Query` with my own doctored `QueryCollection` that duplicates variables with *fixed* names in a middleware.

*But I'm looking for any answer that's more... unhacky?!*

```
public class RequeryMiddleware : IMiddleware
{
    private static readonly char[] separators = new[] { '_', '-', '.', '|' };

    private static bool Requery(ref string name)
    {
        bool changed = false;

        if (name.IndexOfAny(separators) >= 0)
        {
            name = string.Concat(name.Split(separators, StringSplitOptions.None));
            changed = true;
        }

        return changed;
    }

    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context, RequestDelegate next)
    {
        Dictionary<string, StringValues> mods = new(
            StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
        );

        foreach (var item in context.Request.Query)
        {
            string key = item.Key;

            if (Requery(ref key))
            {
                mods.Add(key, item.Value);
            }
        }

        if (mods.Count > 0)
        {
            Dictionary<string, StringValues> query = new(
                context.Request.Query.Count + mods.Count
                , StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase
            );

            foreach (var item in context.Request.Query)
            {
                query.Add(item.Key, item.Value);
            }

            foreach (var mod in mods)
            {
                // if we get here it's bad...
                query.TryAdd(mod.Key, mod.Value);
            }

            // replace the Query collection
            context.Request.Query = new QueryCollection(query);

            // change the QueryString too
            QueryBuilder qb = new(context.Request.Query);
            context.Request.QueryString = qb.ToQueryString();
        }

        return next(context);
    }
}
```